# Deleting gdi objects created by shell32.dll -> ExtractIconEx

Tags: c#, winapi, pinvoke

I'm using ExtractIconEx of the shell32.dll to gather the icons of all files in a specific folder.

It works quite well with one exception: There are hundreds of GDI objects created that never disappear again.

Inclusion code

```
        [DllImport("shell32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    public static extern int ExtractIconEx(string stExeFileName, int nIconIndex, ref IntPtr phiconLarge, ref IntPtr phiconSmall, int nIcons);
```

Usage code

```
foreach (string filename in ListOfFilenames)
{
    IntPtr iconLarge = new IntPtr();
    IntPtr iconSmall = new IntPtr();
    ExtractIconEx(filename, 1 , ref iconLarge, ref iconSmall, 1);
    Image doSomethingWithThis = Icon.FromHandle(iconSmall).ToBitmap();
    .....
}
```

I managed to reproduce that the call of ExtractIconEx which  fills the IntPtr variables is causing the masses of GDI objects (or more the filled iconLarge and iconSmall are the cause here).

I've tried it out a few times with different variants (like ObjectDelete from the interops,...) but nothing seemed to work or it destroyed the program by somehow also eliminating the doSomethingWithThis image.

So the question ehre is what can be done to reduce the unnecessary number of GDI objects? (the interesting part there is that its a total of 5 files in that folder!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648069.aspx):

> You must destroy all icons extracted by ExtractIconEx by calling the DestroyIcon function.

So, each time you call `ExtractIconEx`, you are given two icon handles. Call `DestroyIcon` on them when you are done with them.

FWIW, I'd declare the icon handle parameters as `out` to simply calling the function.

```
[DllImport("shell32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
public static extern uint ExtractIconEx(string stExeFileName, int nIconIndex, 
    out IntPtr phiconLarge, out IntPtr phiconSmall, int nIcons);
```

Then you can call the function like this:

```
IntPtr iconLarge;
IntPtr iconSmall;
uint retval = ExtractIconEx(filename, 1 , out iconLarge, out iconSmall, 1);
```

You should take heed of the return value also.

Comment: Is destroyicon from the same dll?

Comment: Again, you can find this information from the documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ms648063(v=vs.85).aspx  Look at the requirements section of the documentation to find the DLL that contains the function. You can get a functional declaration from pinvoke.net: http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/destroyicon.html?diff=y

Comment: ok found it. question tehre though: Should this also delete: doSomethingWithThis  ?

Comment: That will be collected by GC

Comment: I'm asking as I need the bitmap that is being created via ToBitMap() and when I use destroyicon that bitmap also disappears

Comment: Ok solved it. your solution in combination with: Image doSomethingWithThis = new Bitmap(Icon.FromHandle(iconSmall).ToBitmap()); did the job. tnx

Comment: When are you calling `DestroyIcon`? After the call to `ToBitmap`?

Comment: yes. The problem was that ToBitmap() only creates a shallow copy (thus the same image data is used or something like that). With using the constructor to copy the whole image into a new bitmap I circumvented that and still could reduce the gdi count drastically (without the destroyicon it was 6k with the destroyicon it is now down to 100 despite4 the deep copy of the image through the bitmap-constructor)

Comment: I'm glad you understand this part of it. I know little about the .net framework.

Comment: I had to look up how exactly to do a deep copy myself (didn't count on the bitmap constructor having this ability already) but with that addon your answer works superbly. tnx again